# Node And Mongodb - run script every 24 hours

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using node.js and mongoose. 
I need a numerical value in every mongoose document to increase by 25,000 every 24 hours.

Is There a better way than:

```
thing.lastUpdated = new Date();
```

And

```
if(/* check how many days(if any) since lase update */> 0){
    for(var i = 0;i<days;i++){
        //update value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) to schedule an increment job

Comment: what about flask and mongoengine?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use-cases, you could possibly calculate it based on a *create date* with a [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals):

```
var ThingSchema = new Schema({
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

ThingSchema.virtual('numerical').get(function () {
    if (!this.created) return 0;

    var delta = (Date.now() - this.created) || 0;

    return 25000 * Math.floor(delta / 86400000);
});
```

```
// `created` 2 days ago
new Thing({ created: Date.now() - 172800000 }).save(function (thing) {
    console.log(thing.numerical);
});
```